# HTML/CSS Onclick divs automatically hiding

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if this had already been asked but I have two onclick divs and what I want to do is for example: I open the first one but then when I open the second one I want the first one to close automatically and the other way around.

Here's the HTML:

```js
    function myFunction() {
       var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
         if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
         } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
         }
    }

     function myFunction2() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
             x.style.display = "block";
          } else {
              x.style.display = "none";                  }
     }
```

```css
  #myDIV {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    top: 150px;
  }

  .button1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 120px
  }
  
  #myDIV2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

  .button2 {
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
 
 <button class="button1" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<button class="button2" onclick="myFunction2()">Try it2</button>

<div id="myDIV2">
This is my second DIV element.
</div>
```

**DEMO:** https://codepen.io/pen/NWrZBRX

Comment: reset display to both of your divs inside the function : `function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get both divs in both functions then. Then hide whichever one you want and show the other one. You also only need one function because it is just reversing whatever you already did. I also made it so the button is always on top of the div by using z-index:1; because it was being hidden some of the time below the divs.

(this can be done in your existing code by doing the following)

```css
  #myDIV {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    top: 150px;
  }

  .button1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 120px
    z-index:1;
  }
  
  #myDIV2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

  .button2 {
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            test
        </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="legStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="button1" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <div id="myDIV">
            This is my DIV element.
        </div>
        <div id="myDIV2">
            This is my second DIV element.
        </div>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
              const x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
              const y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
              if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
                y.style.display = "none"
              } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
                y.style.display = "block"
              }
            }
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```